# wordpress unique Voting using a cookie system to prevent revoting for each post

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, wordpress

I'm trying to create a voting system for a wordpress theme. I'm using a cookies system to make sure the voters only vote once, but the problem is when a user votes for a post the voted cookie is set to 1 and if they want to vote for another post because the cookie is set to 1 they can't. How can I get around this problem and have unique votes for each wordpress post?

I am using the following code to set the cookie

```
setcookie('voted','1');
```

and I use an if statement to see if the user has voted or not:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["voted"]){
     // vote up code
}
```

Comment: Controlling votes using client cookies is like not controlling at all. You **must** control that using data stored on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You could try storing the id of poll in the voted cookie.

```
<?php
setcookie("voted[$id_of_poll]", $id_of_poll);
```

And then check it like this

```
<?php
if (in_array($id_of_poll, $_COOKIE['voted']))
{
   // already voted
}
```

**However be aware that cookies are highly volitile.** Users can clear them, they may use multiple devices, etc. You're better off storing this in your own database against the users id.

Answer (score 1):

Append the post ID to the cookie so it's unique:

```
setcookie("voted-".get_the_ID(),'1');
```

And something like this:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["voted-".get_the_ID()]){
     // vote up code
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that flood the cookie cache with cookies? what if the user votes for 50 posts then there would be 50 cookies set in the browser history. isn't that a problem?

Comment: Yes, since there are only so many cookies you can have per site (about 180 in real world tests). The better option, which would be a lot to document here, is to create a voting record table in the database and store votes into that. Also generate a random session ID and store that with each vote. Set that session ID on the user as a cookie. Then you can look up in that table for each vote if they've voted or not.